# How get an parent id in HasMany field Laravel Nova

Tags: laravel-nova

i have **Category** resource which have a nested **Items** resources via **HasMany** field

```
public function fields(Request $request)
    {
        return [

            new Panel('Items', [
                HasMany::make('Items', 'items')
            ]),
        ];
    }
```

I need to perform specific validation with **Items**: the **Category** have integer field max_default_items so when creating a new Item inside the category i need to check, does max_default_items is greater than the actual count of items with **is_default** flag. The problem is that i have no idea how to get the **Category** id inside **Item**

Is it possible to pass params to HasMany field and get it inside **Items** resource?

Please help!

Comment: Hi Nazar, did you manage to get the category id inside hasmany?